# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Have an angular application:

This is part of my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ReApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>REApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="./lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This is part of my server.js(start point):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/api', api);
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html');
});
```

Problem is: when i have one route (localhost:3000/first) everything working. When i have route something like that: localhost:3000/first/second, i have an error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html". In the terminal i have get request - first/second/lib/angular/angular.min.js. Of course i don't have that link. May who knows how to set a start page for this links in undex.html?

Comment: don't use relative path to stylesheet or use a base tag. Try removing the leading dot in your paths to make them absolute

Comment: ohhhh, thanx, writing <baser href='/'>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue all you have to do is place the `<base href="/">` element just below the `<title>` element in the head section of `index.html` page.

Comment: it didn't work for me. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using packages installed by bower (the same should work for npm or yarn or any other package manager installed packages as well).

Add this middleware somewhere in your express code, before any other route declarations.

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/bower_components')));
```

The first argument `/assets` is just a virtual path that doesn't have to exist in your project, and the second one is telling express to serve static assets from the `bower_components` folder.
Next, in your markup, have your stylesheet inclusions like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bulma/css/bulma.min.css">
```